# Commenting hsx blaze-html lines in Haskell

Tags: haskell, html-templates, blaze-html, ihp

I'm starting to experiment with [IHP's webframework](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/hsx.html). I am testing some different page layouts and I can't seem to find the right way of commenting out html within the hsx QuasiQuote (which has the blaze-html syntax) whilst experimenting with the design. For example, I want to temporarily comment the link to Users in the following:

```
 [hsx |
 <a class="nav-link active" href={UsersAction}> Users  </a>
 <a class="nav-link active" href={SitesAction}> Current Projects </a>
 <a class="nav-link active" href={NewSiteAction}> Add New Project </a>
 |]
```

I have tried commenting the line html style:

```
[hsx |
  <!-- <a class="nav-link active" href={UsersAction}> Users  </a> -->
|]
```

but that yields a compilation error:

```
unexpected '!'
```

I have also tried escaping it in curly braces as a haskell comment but that yields

```
compileToHaskell(-- <a class="nav-link active" href={UsersAction}> Users  </a>   ): "0\nSrcLoc \"\" 1 65\nParse error: EOF\n"
```

Essentially I am looking for a way to comment lines or blocks of code  within an [hsx|...|] QuasiQuote block but I am unsure of what exactly I need to escape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HSX previously had no support for HTML comments. I've just added this to the HSX syntax: https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/pull/349

Will be part of the next version of IHP released later today. Then this syntax will work:

```html
[hsx|
<div>
    <!-- Comment -->
</div>
|]
```